# javascript: defining var in constructor makes it unusable

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have written this code in javascript:

```js
var engiszik;
var numOfCitizens = 10;

function Engiszi()
{
  var chance = random(0, 100);
  this.type = chance < 67 ? "r" : (chance < 87 ? "o" : "p");
  this.mood = ((type === "o") ? random(60, 100, false) : (type === "p" ? random(0, 20) : random(0, 100, false)));
  this.changePlace = random(0, 15, false);
}

initialize();
function initialize()
{
  engiszik = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < numOfCitizens; i ++)
    engiszik.push(new Engiszi());
}
```

`random` works correctly and returns a number. The `?:` parts also seem to be correct (not entirely sure: can the lack of parentheses cause errors in it?).

When I load the page, I get the error "type not found" at the line `engiszik.push(new Engiszi());`. If I remove the variable `chance` from the constructor of `Engiszi` (and the things that use it), it seems to work.

What causes this? Does the `var` in the constructor change `Engiszi` into a normal function instead of a constructor? How can I find a way around this (I really need `chance`, but I don't want to declare it as a global variable if possible)?

Comment: var in a ctor is allowed. Something else is going funny with your code. Since you've only posted part of it (your example doesn't run), I imagine it's in one of the other parts.

Comment: Have you looked at `return`ing it from the `Engiszi` function?

Comment: may try `Math.random();` instead of just `random()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets follow where the error is coming from back beyond the invocation line

> "type not found" at the line `engiszik.push(new Engiszi());`

Step into `new Engiszi()`, look for `type`,

```
this.mood = ((type === "o") ? random(60, 100, false) : (type === "p" ? random(0, 20) : random(0, 100, false)));
//            ^^^^                                      ^^^^
```

Where is `type` defined? did you mean `this.type`?

Comment: Yes. I thought it meant the type "Engiszi", but apparently it was this.type. Adding "this." to "type" solved the problem.